# ubuntu upgrade from mysql to maria db

Tags: 16.04, mysql, mariadb

First a backup all my databases

```
mysqldump -u caiofior -p --all-databases > /home/caiofior/all.sql
```

Then uninstall mysql

```
sudo apt-get purge $(sudo dpkg -l | grep -E 'mysql-(server|client|commom)' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Remove all config files

```
sudo rm -Rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql*
```

Then install mariadb

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Restore the databases

```
sudo mysql < /home/caiofior/all.sql
```

Restarts mariadb service

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And it crashes with the logs

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer 2017-06-14 10:26:19 CEST; 12s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 5885 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

giu 14 10:25:49 portattile-caiofior mysqld[6058]: 170614 10:25:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'blackhole' already installed
giu 14 10:25:49 portattile-caiofior mysqld[6058]: 170614 10:25:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'federated' already installed
giu 14 10:25:49 portattile-caiofior mysqld[6058]: 170614 10:25:49 [ERROR] Plugin 'innodb' already installed
giu 14 10:25:49 portattile-caiofior mysqld[6058]: 170614 10:25:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
giu 14 10:25:49 portattile-caiofior mysqld[6058]: 170614 10:25:49 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged or in unsupported 3.20 format.
giu 14 10:26:19 portattile-caiofior mysql[5885]: ...fail!
giu 14 10:26:19 portattile-caiofior systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
giu 14 10:26:19 portattile-caiofior systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
giu 14 10:26:19 portattile-caiofior systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
giu 14 10:26:19 portattile-caiofior systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the dump, I backup also mysql database with user and permissions and it crash maria db.

So **before** restoring the data backup your mysql database data

```
sudo mysqldump mysql > /home/caiofior/mysql.sql
```

And after restoring all the data restore previous mysql database

```
sudo mysqladmin drop mysql
sudo mysqladmin create mysql
sudo mysql mysql < /home/caiofior/mysql.sql
```